# PostgreSQL Deferrable constraints

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

In this part of code I insert data in tables.

```
//some code...
const classIdArr = request.body.classIdArr;

await dbPool.query('BEGIN');
const result = await dbPool.query('Insert Into T_SUBJECT (NAME, NAME_ENG) Values ($1, $2) Returning ID', [subject.name, subject.name_eng]);

const subjectId = result.rows[0].id;

await Promise.all(classIdArr.map(async (classId) => {
    await dbPool.query('Insert Into T_BIND_SUBJECT_CLASS (CLASS_ID, SUBJECT_ID) Values ($1, $2)', [classId, subjectId]);
}));
await dbPool.query('COMMIT');

//some code...
```

T_BIND_SUBJECT_CLASS has constraints. There is one of them

```
...
CONSTRAINT t_bind_subject_class_fk_subject FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
        REFERENCES public.t_subject (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
        NOT VALID
...
```

if classIdArr has length === 1 there is no problem, but if > 1 - postgreSQL throws error:

> insert or update on table 
>   "t_bind_subject_class" violates foreign key constraint
>   "t_bind_subject_class_fk_subject"

Why? This constraint is DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED. As I understand it, this means that all checks occur at the end of the transaction, but in this case they are checked after the first insertion

Please, help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a connection pool, so the statements in your code may be executed using different connections, i.e. in different transactions.

Comment: Oh, and what can I do in this case?

Comment: Follow the [doc](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions)